# What is the maximum crosswind component for large airliners?

Tags: aircraft-performance, crosswind

For smaller aircraft like Cessnas, the demonstrated crosswind component is something like 12 knots but they can land up to 20 to 25 knots. For bigger jets, such as the Boeing 737 and 777, what is the maximum crosswind component?

Comment: “Jumbo jet” usually means 747 specifically, not just any large jet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This link](http://www.theairlinepilots.com/forumarchive/b777/b777memoryitemsandlimitations.pdf) says 38 knots for the 777.
[This link](http://www.smartcockpit.com/aircraft-ressources/Limitations_(B777).html) says 25 knots for the 777 autoland system.

[This site](http://www.b737.org.uk/limitations.htm) says for the:

- 737-200, crosswind limit is 31 knots;
- for the 737-300 thru -500, 35 knots;
- for the 737-600 thru -900, 36 knots; and
- for the 737-600 thru -900 with winglets, 33 knots.

Answer (score 3):

[From this site](http://www.planeandpilotmag.com/pilot-talk/ntsb-debriefer/the-crosswind-component.html#.VWBqSoeydLw):

> During the type certification process, the FAA requires the manufacturer to demonstrate that its airplane can be controlled in 90° crosswinds up to 20% of V<sub>S<sub>0</sub></sub>.